# Is there a way to map the specific Launch configuration per file in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

What if I want to run `streamlit` for `app.py` and `python` for the rest of `*.py` files. How can I skip selection step and use only a quick combination of `Ctrl+F5` (or `F5`) letting VSCode decide based on the file name?

I added multiple launch configs into `.vscode/launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: app.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "streamlit",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "args": [
                "run",
                "app.py"
            ],
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "You can now view your Streamlit app in your browser",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:8501",
                "action": "openExternally"
              }
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

so now I can select any of them to run a file currently open in the VSCode, but I'd like to save some time.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.57.0.

Together with the extension [Launch Configs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config) by ArturoDent you can define a `F5` replace key binding that launches a config based on the current editor file:

```json
  {
    "key": "f5",
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.transform",
    "when": "debuggersAvailable && debugState == 'inactive'",
    "args": {
      "text": "${command:launchCommand}",
      "command": {
        "launchCommand": {
          "command": "${transform:launchCommand}",
          "transform": {
            "launchCommand": {
              "text": "${command:launchCommand}",
              "command": {
                "launchCommand": {
                  "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
                  "args": {
                    "app.py": "launches.Streamlit",
                    "@default": "launches.OtherPython"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You need to edit `settings.json` for Launch Configs:

```json
  "launches": {
    "Streamlit": "Python: app.py",
    "OtherPython": "Python: Current File"
  }
```

Maybe you need to add a workspace/Folder designation, see Launch Configs docs.